# Is there a way to match a sub matrix out of a bigger matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, pattern-matching

It is a 2D matrix matching problem. Given a bigger matrix find a smaller matrix, which matches the digits in the bigger matrix. Till here its easy, since I can use Rabin Karp matching and find the sub matrix, but here's the twist there can be alphabets in the sub matrix and the alphabets should match the same digits throughout the sub matrix matching.
eg.

Big Matrix:

```
[
      [2, 5, 2, 5, 2],
      [5, 1, 5, 2, 3],
      [1, 5, 2, 5, 4]
]
```

Sub matrix:

```
[
      [5, a],
      [a, e]
]
```

This should match `a` to the same digits, and `e` can be any digit.
So here the match is at `(1, 0)`, because `5` matches `5` at `(1, 0)` and `a=1` at `[(1,1), (2,0)]` and `e=5`.

**Edit:**
Added Constraints

Constraints:

1 <= length(Big Matrix) <= 50

1 <= length(any row in Big Matrix) <= 50

1 <= length(Sub Matrix) <= min(length(Board Matrix), length(Board Matrix[row size]))

Big Matrix will contain just digits, but Sub matrix can contain either alphabets or digits.
Conditions:

1. Any digit should correspond to the same digit in the Big Matrix.
2. Any letter should corresponding to a digit should correspond to the same digit throughout the submatrix.
3. Any two distinct letters should correspond to two different digits. i.e no two characters can have the same digit mapped.

Comment: What did you attempt?

Comment: I did sliding window, but that would take a very long run time.

Comment: Considering samgak's answer, I think you need to provide more information about the actual problem that you're trying to solve. What are typical/maximum sizes for the matrix, and sub matrix? What is the range of numbers used in the matrix? How many unique letters can be in the sub matrix?

Comment: I have added the constraints, if you would like any additional details, please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand what the difficulty is. In a comment, it was mentioned that the time limit is 4 seconds. Worst case for a brute force algorithm is that the big matrix is 50x50 and the sub matrix is 25x25. So there are 25x25 positions for the sub matrix, and each one takes at most 25x25 comparisons. With a O(n^4) solution, the running time is some small constant factor times 25^4. That's only 390625 operations, which a modern desktop can easily do in half a second.

Comment: @user3386109: a little more must be spent to check the conditions 2. and 3.

Comment: The pattern matrix contains a 5. So is e=5 allowed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Very little time, since a 10 entry array is all that's needed to track the translation from letter to digit, and a 10 entry boolean array is all that's needed to verify that the mappings are unique.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your matrix contains single digits and the number of variables isn't too large, you could precompute the submatrix hashes for all possible values of a and e (in this case 100 of them) and store them in a data structure such as a hash set. Then as you compute your rolling hash as part of the Rabin-Karp matching algorithm, you can check if the hash is in the hash set at each step. This check should be O(1).

Comment: So, the constraints are there can be any lower case alphabet, but no two alphabet can share the same value. And there will be only single digit values. But don't you think calculating all possible values of a and e will take a very big space complexity?

Comment: This method won't be efficient, since I won't know the value of a and e while rolling hash so I will have to use all the values for a and e in the rolling hash as well, to match. Hence this won't be efficient at all.

Comment: If the values are single digits and no two variables can share the same value there will be only 90 possible values of a and e. However the number will increase exponentially as the number of variables increases, which is a limitation, you are trading time complexity while iterating over the large matrix for space complexity and increased initial time complexity. It will only be efficient for a matrices over a certain size. Regarding your second comment, no you don't need to compute the hash for all values of a and e, you compute the hash for the actual values in your big matrix.

Comment: Would you recommend using more memory to save the time complexity? The time limit is just 4 seconds, and worst case iterating through all the elements is O((mn)**2).

Comment: You could do that but it would be a different algorithm and I'm not aware of one. There most likely exists a better/faster algorithm than the one I am suggesting, but it has the advantage of being fairly straightforward to implement, especially if you can adapt an existing implementation of Rabin-Karp.

Answer (score 1):

**Thinking aloud:**

Preprocess the pattern to list

- the digit entries;
- the letters, grouped by equal values, possibly setting singletons aside.

Perform a pattern search on the digits alone, using brute force (or possibly matrix search with don't care symbols ?). For every candidate,

- check that the letter assignments are compatible (condition 2.), not needed for singletons,
- check that the assignments are unique (condition 3.).